# How to override the base class method without creating object for base class if you know anyone can you give the example?

Tags: java

I also done this example creating object for both class and call the method is there anyway to override the baseclass?

```
class Car {
    void Max() {
        System.out.println("Audi");
    }
}

class Speed extends Car {
    void Max() {
        System.out.println("300");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Speed s=new Speed();
        s.Max();
    }
}
```

Comment: perhaps see [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Comment: .....Huh? Method overriding is pretty independent from object instantiation.... Unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What have you tried that didn't work as expected and what do you want instead?

Comment: i just want to access base class.

Comment: Provide code example.

Comment: class Car
  {
   void run()
       {
         System.out.println("Audi");
       }
}
class Speed extends Car
  {
   void Max()
       {
         System.out.println("300");
       }
public static void main(String args[])
{
Speed s=new Speed();
s.Max();
}
}

o/p
 
 300
  ?
  
    i want the base class output without creating object for that one

Comment: If all you can use are instance methods, you can't really. Creating a `new Speed()` can be considered akin to also creating a `new Car()` because in your class hierarchy a `Speed` is-a `Car`, but I suppose that point could be argued...

Comment: Thank you Luiggi Mendoza but i want this order       o/p Audi 300

Comment: So, what about `s.run(); s.Max();`? Seriously, the fact you're new to Java doesn't mean you cannot experiment the code yourself and get your own answers.

Comment: it's correct **user3580294** but don't want to create the object okay it is possible tell me sir

Comment: If you want to access the instance method you'll have to either create an object of that class or a derivative of that object. Period.

Comment: You can call s.run() from the base class -- nothing is stopping you.

Comment: **Luiggi Mendoza** okay this wise we have to call the method **s.run(); s.Max();** so i knew that creating the object and call the base class and derived class mehod okay.i don't want to create the object for parent class,that's why i'm telling without creating object for parent class and calling the method like **obj name.run()** i want the output can you do.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being called a "give me the repz" type person...hopefully this helps:

This first class is a BaseClass, you can create a new one by writing:

```
BaseClass myBaseClass = new BaseClass();

public class BaseClass {
    private int aNumber; //This global variable is private and so cannot be overwritten.
    int anotherNumber; //This global variable is package scope and so can be accessed by sub-classes in the same package.
    protected yetAnotherNumber; //This variable is accessible by any subclasses.
    public int numberAvailableToEveryone; //This global variable is accessible to anyone and everyone.

    public BaseClass() {} //This is a constructor (no return type)

    private void myPrivateMethod() {} //This method cannot be overwritten

    void packageScopeMethod() {}

    protected void thisMethodCanBeOverwrittenBySubClasses() {}

    public void theWorldCanCallMe() {} //extendable to the world, not much different than protected scope tbh 
}
```

Now, to overwrite a method you can create an anonymous class like so:

```
BaseClass myAnonymousClass = new BaseClass() {
      public void theWorldCanCallMe() {
          //in here you can override the method to do whatever you want.
      }
}
```

or you could define a subclass like so:

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public void tehWorldCanCallMe() {
         //again your new code goes here
    }
}
```

and then instantiate it like so:

```
SubClass myClassThatOverridesAMethod = new SubClass();
```

---

A car example closer to your code:

```
class Car {

    private String name;
    int speed = 100;

    Car(String name) {  //This is the base classes constructor
        this.name = name;
    }

    String max() {
       return speed;
    }

    void run() {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(max()); //will print the base speed unless overridden
    }
}

class Audi extends Car {
    Audi() {
        super("Audi")
    }
}

class Speed extends Car {

    Speed() {
        super("Speed");
    }
    @Override
    String max() {
        speed = 300;
        return speed;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Speed s=new Speed();
        s.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the language barrier is really inhibiting my ability to determine exactly what you are asking...but I can try to add in a Car example as per what you're doing....1 sec.